# Simple algorithm for generating Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, algorithms, random

I found a very simple algorithm that draws values from a Poisson distribution from [this project.](http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/research/javasimulation/javasimulation-1.1/docs/report.pdf)

The algorithm's code in Java is:

```
public final int poisson(double a) {
        double limit = Math.exp(-a), prod = nextDouble();
        int n;
        for (n = 0; prod >= limit; n++)
            prod *= nextDouble();
        return n;
        }
```

[`nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) is a function from the `Random` package in Java that returns a uniformly distributed random `double`, for example `0.885598042879084`.

I can't understand how this creates a Poisson distribution.

Can someone explain?

Comment: what is nextDouble()?

Comment: @PA6OTA Good question, I added the meaning and a link to the API. Sorry for leaving it out initially

Answer (score 4):

It is related to the Poisson process: suppose $a$ is fixed and $N$ is the number of independent Exponential (mean 1) RV's to be added until the sum exceeds $a$. In this case, $N \sim Poisson(a)$.

In the code above, everything is anti-logged. For example, instead of adding Exponentials, they multiply Uniforms, due to the relation $Y = - \ln(U)$ is an Exponential (mean 1) RV whenever $U$ is Uniform[0,1].

Comment: doesn't help too much...

Comment: And yet this is exactly the reason why the algorithm works.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that we have $k$ independent and identically distributed exponential random variables $X_1, \dotsc, X_k$ with parameter $\lambda$. If we define a counting process $\{N(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ such that $S_k := X_1 + \dotsb + X_k$ is the occurring time of the $k$-th event, then this is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. This means that $\mathbb{P}\{N(t) \leq k\} = \mathbb{P}\{S_k \geq t\}$, or more informally that you can describe the distribution of $N(t)$ through the distribution of $S_k$.

Now consider that if $X$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$, then $Y := F_X(X) = 1 - e^{-\lambda X}$ is a standard uniform random variable (here $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$). Note also that
$$
F_X^{-1}(Y) = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\log(1 - Y)
$$
is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$. Since also $U := 1 - Y$ is a standard uniform random variable, the random variable
$$
X' = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\log U
$$
is again an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$.

We want to count (at most) $k$ events in a given time interval $[0, t]$ (that we can suppose without loss of generality to be $[0, 1]$, i.e. we arbitrarily fix $t = 1$), that is we want $N(1) \leq k$. By what we observed at the beginning, this corresponds to the condition $S_k \geq 1$, which, in its turn, corresponds to the following:
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^k X_i \geq 1 \iff \sum_{i = 1}^k -\frac{1}{\lambda}\log U_i \geq 1 \iff -\frac{1}{\lambda}\log\bigg( \prod_{i = 1}^k U_i \bigg) \geq 1 \iff
\prod_{i = 1}^k U_i \leq e^{-\lambda},
$$
which is precisely what is described in Knuth's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

> The Poisson distribution is a discrete probability distribution that expresses the probability of a given number of events occurring in a fixed interval of time and/or space if these events occur with a known average rate and independently of the time since the last event.

I think that you could get something similar by adding together random values until you hit a maximum, as the random function has a "known average rate" and is basically "independent" of the last function call. It looks to me like multiplying it like so is just a transformation to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the previous answer is correct. This is simply a version of Knuth's algorithm.  It gets slower the larger the parameter lambda.