# Algorithm to generate deviate for a Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

According to a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785188/simple-algorithm-for-generating-poisson-distribution), the following algorithm generates deviates of a Poisson distribution:

```
static Random random = new Random();
public static final int generatePoissonDeviate(double a) {
    double limit = Math.exp(-a);
    double product = random.nextDouble();
    int n;
    for( n = 0; product >= limit; n++ ) product *= random.nextDouble();
    return n;
}
```

What is "a" in this algorithm? It does not appear to be a mean.

When I run this algorithm it does not generate any zeroes.

I want to generate deviates of a Poisson distribution with a mean value N that includes zeroes. For example, assume number of children per family has a Poisson distribution and the mean number of children per family is 2.5. How can I generate deviates for individual families? Obviously the deviates must include the possibility of a family having zero children.

Answer (score 1):

The "a" in your algorithm is the mean of the Poisson distribution, you are simulating from: The output is the realization of a Poisson variate of mean $a$.

The algorithm should generate zeroes, and it looks fine when I run it. I don't have Eclipse on this machine, so here's the C# version, which generates plenty of zeroes.

```
    static Random random = new Random();
    public static int generatePoissonDeviate(double a)
    {
        double limit = Math.Exp(-a);
        double product = random.NextDouble();
        int n;
        for (n = 0; product >= limit; n++)
        {
            product *= random.NextDouble();
        }
        return n;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(generatePoissonDeviate(2.5));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a really efficient implementation of a routine taking a mean, using a flat random generator (on (0,1) and delivering a Poisson deviate:

http://www.fnal.gov/docs/working-groups/fpcltf/Pkg/CLHEP/Random/RandPoisson.cc

I wrote this some years ago.  It is in C++, but you should be able to discern the algorithm from this code even if you don't want to use C++.  Lhe lnGamma routine is based on Numerical Recipes.

Comment: Why is it so much more complicated than the algorithm I quoted?

Comment: Because it is roughly 2.5 times faster in that it takes at average fewer than half the calls to the uniform random generator.  But for the PO's purpose, your code (with the error corrected)  might be better because it is simpler.